# How to disable displaying suggestions in Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Can I programmatically disable the display of a "Sugested Words" for TEdit on the virtual keyboard in the Delphi Android?

In Java it is simple:

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SearchText);
et.setInputType(et.getInputType()
    | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
    | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER);
```

But in Delphi, I not found the setInputType.

Comment: Take a look at - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Types.TVirtualKeyboardType - set keyboard type to Alphabet

Comment: Unfortunately I have not found anything that has helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Set the `TEdit.KeyboardType` to `Alphabet`:

[image]

Documentation [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Types.TVirtualKeyboardType) says:

> Alphabet    An alphanumeric keyboard for general text input.
>
> On Android, the Alphabet keyboard type has no word completion/word
>   suggestion. The keyboard looks the same as the Default keyboard, but
>   without suggestions.

To achieve the same **programmatically** write f.ex.

```
Edit1.KeyboardType := Alphabet;
```

Comment: That's what I've post as a comment and @KJAN replied.

Comment: Yes @RBA I can see that. I don't know what KJAN is missing.

Comment: You have read the question wrong! I need to disable displaying suggestions and not set the keyboard to Alphabet...

Comment: @KJAN Did you read the quote from the documentation? *"... but without suggestions"*

Comment: The documentation "often" cannot be trusted. Must try it. And then giving the minus sign for the question ...

Comment: @KJAN I'm not sure I understand you. Do you mean that the documentation is wrong, and that suggestions are shown? Or was your test successful? BTW, I did not give you any minus signs.

Comment: I tested it. And that suggestions are shown. Sometimes the documentation did not match the reality.

Comment: So it looks like that bug (at least for now) found only on SAMSUNG devices.

Comment: I have created a issue on Embarcadero quality (see https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14831)

Comment: Very good @KJAN that you had the opportunity to test on so many devices. Interesting that it works correctly on Acer with Android 5.0 but not on SM-G360F with Android 5.0.2. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the fully native Android/ios Tedit here:

(svn) https://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/

and simply do

```
MyEdit.EditText.setInputType(MyEdit.EditText.getInputType()
    | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
    | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER);
```